# Get Android application version from REST request

Tags: android, http, version, android-volley

> Is it possible to find out which version of my application the user is running just from http request he sends (application is using Volley library)?

I'm working on an application that was completely free and now some features should be available to paying customers only. The problem is, I can't force people to update application if they don't want to. Is it possible to check app version on a server just from headers of http requests I'm sending with Volley?

Comment: if you're not sending the headers no. But you can put the header on the new version and `if(headers == null)` you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks, this should be helpful, but still.. I would like to know if there is any other way without updating application, just from default headers, maybe "user-agent" header?

Comment: As far as I know: No, sorry

Comment: Thanks anyway, your comment was very helpful.